# PHPlot: Popup occur when hover on a graph points

Tags: php, phplot

Is there a way to display a pop up when mouse arrow is on a specific graph points by using PHPlot. If no than which other library can provide me this functionality.

Comment: There's a cool service called Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPlot appears to generate an image so it wouldn't be easy to create a hover effect for individual bars.

You could investigate HTML effects that allow you to trigger links for different locations on an image, but this could be an extensively manual process for each chart. (see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp for e.g.)

Perhaps investigate a library like [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) that include this kind of function already?